# Get last item by date in mongoDB and distict id field?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that stores documents with the following structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82853464934e0ced4dcb"), "id_process" : 2, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:42:12" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82803464932c4838b3fb"), "id_process" : 2, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:42:07" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a825e34649336ac628ba8"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:41:33" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82593464934884a59263"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:41:28" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a81b93464935cf41d3455"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:38:47" }
```

How can I get the information of the distinct id_process with lastest date "fecha_termina"

I tried with 
`db.log.find({}).sort({"fecha_termina":-1})` It works but show all registers
`db.log.distinct("id_process")` It works but I only get the id_process [1,2]
`db.log.distinct("id_process").sort({"fecha_termina":-1})` Not working
`db.log.distinct("id_process",{}).sort({"fecha_termina":-1})`  Not working
I don't understand agreggate option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
db.log.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$id_process",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: "$data",
              cond: {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.fecha_termina",
                  {
                    $max: "$data.fecha_termina"
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$data"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MXK8VUly-cA)

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
{ 
  $group: { 
      _id: "$id_process", 
      latest_fecha_termina: { 
          $max: { $dateFromString: { dateString: "$fecha_termina" } } 
      }
  }
},
{
  $project: {
      id_process: "$_id",
      _id: 0,
      latest_fecha_termina: { 
          $dateToString: {
              date: "$latest_fecha_termina",
              format: "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
          } 
      }
  }
}
] )
```

returns:

```
{ "id_process" : 2, "latest_fecha_termina" : "03/12/2020 01:42:12" }
{ "id_process" : 1, "latest_fecha_termina" : "03/12/2020 01:41:33" }
```